# How to relate Java Jar file With CVE(Mitre CVE Database)

Tags: security

We have to find out any `Mitre CVE` attached to a `jar` file. From CVE database, I am only getting vendor name and product name information.

Now I am really not sure how to relate Java jar file to CVE.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a 3rd party tool like [Victims CVE Database Version Search](https://github.com/adedov/victims-version-search) will help you. The source code might also answer the question of how to create the relation between CVE and specific version of a JAR file.

Comment: Thank you, I tried a similar tool "Owasp Dependency Check". Previously I was trying to do this(Relating jar with CVE) myself but finally, I got the whole cake  already cooked ready to eat.